# Void methods cannot return a value -Java

Tags: java

I am sure this is a dumb question but i have been at it for quite a bit.. I am trying to create a java program that calculates compound interest based off a user input of years and amount of money. But i keep getting an error that a void method cannot return a value. So i switch the method to a double because thats what will be returned, but than it tells me that a double method must return a double. Even tho im returning a double in the loop... Please help

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            **strong text**
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); //creates scanner

            System.out.println("Enter number of years until retirement: "); //asks user to input number of years until retirement
            int Years = reader.nextInt();

            if (Years <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number"); //if the number of years was invalid, exits the program and asks to enter a valid number
                System.exit(0);
            }


            System.out.println("Enter amount of money able to save annually: "); //asks user how much money they can input
            double MoneySaved = reader.nextInt();

            reader.close(); //closes scanner


            for(int i=0; i < Years; i++)
            {

                Total = MoneySaved * 1.05;

                return Total;



            }
            System.out.println("You will have $" + df.format(TotalAmount) + " saved up by retirement");



        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the method? i see only main method.

Comment: A for loop is not a method, not sure I see your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your for to this

```
    Double total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < Years; i++) {
        total += MoneySaved;
        total *= 1.05;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the method a double and change

```
double MoneySaved = reader.nextInt();
```

to

```
double MoneySaved = reader.nextDouble();
```

Also I do not see your declaration of 'Total'; make sure that is declared as a double.

Answer (score 0):

First, main Java method must be void and void methods cannot return a value(even compiler tells you that), although you can use a return statement to break execution of the method and return to calling method.

So answering your question, you have to create method that returns double and then just prints it in your main method or do not return anything and just replace

```
return Total;
```

with

```
System.out.println("You will have $" + df.format(Total) + " saved up by retirement");
```

PS: it looks like you are new to Java, so for a start read some content about Java, for example [offical oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html)